# How to preview an Illustrator document at different rasterized sizes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, favicon

I'm designing a favicon in Illustrator and I'd like to see what it would look like in pixels at 128px and 16px as I'm working on it.  Is this possible?

**Edit** Found the answer - posted below.

Answer (score 4):

you can do any version of your design while you are working in a bigger version of it by using **symbols** here you are the steps.

1. illustrate you design in any dimension you like.
2. select all your final illustration and drag and drop it in the symbols panel, and name it as you want.
3. now drag your new symbol into your artboard dag as many versions you want to export.
4. resize the instant copy of your dropped symbols to meet the rasterized versions, for example, scale one of the symbols to 128px X 128px and the other 16px X 16px.
5. now every change you made to the bigger version of your design will affect the two versions of your instant symbol.
6. for more accuracy you can switch your view to **pixel view** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>

now you every time you want to work on to a new version you just drop a new symbol into your artboard and resize it to your desire dimension. and when you want to change the small version of your icon just double click the bigger version of the symbol and change it in the isolated mode. and this will ensure modifying the other version.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is certainly a different way of doing it than I came up with.  Personally I prefer my method, so I'll be marking mine as the answer, but I've +1 your good answer.

Answer (score 3):

After digging around some more, I realized it behaves just like Photoshop.  `Window > New Window`, then adjust the window appearance accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a quick `File > Save for Web` (<kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), and then adjust the image size to see what it will look like.

[image: Save for Web]

Then just press `Cancel` (<kbd>Esc</kbd>) to back out to your drawing. You don't have to actually save it, just use it as a preview.

Comment: Thanks for the response - but that's too much work to do that after every little tweak.  I was able to find how to open new windows & change my view that way.  Still - your response is appreciated.